# Perspective view Distorted

Tags: 3d-view

I’m using Blender 2.92 Normally When suddenly the perspective view got distorted as shown on the first picture

1-  The orthographic view works fine as shown on the Second picture.

2-  There’s no camera in the view because I’m in the modeling phase.

3-  When I create a new file, the perspective works OK with no distortion.

What Should I do??

[image]

Comment: Go to view > Focal Length, the default is 50

Comment: Or to File → Defaults → Load Factory Settings (this will change all custom settings though, so use this in case you only just started out with Blender).

Comment: @Gorgious Thank you my man. Focal Length was 1 so I changed it & it worked.